# Normalize JSON Object from a multiple column dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract some information of a JSON I got from a request, but have some troubles at one point.

As my data is a nested JSON, I first used

```
df = json_normalize(response)
```

to get the infos into a df. But as a result I get a df, which still has a column with JSON-style information in it, which I can't extract with json_normalize anymore.
The df looks like:

```
id    duration     columnA                            
1     12         [{"A": "600", "B": "30", "C": "50"},{"A": "200", "B": "35", "C": "50"}]  
2     5          [{"A": "300", "B": "70", "C": "80"},{"A": "400", "B": "76", "C": "90"}]
```

But when I am trying

```
df2 = json_normalize(df['columnA'])
```

I only get an error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'"

As result I would like to get a df like:

```
A   B   C
600 30  50
200 35  50
300 70  80
400 76  90
```

Comment: post your `response` contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can normalise each of the inner objects and `concat` the resulting dataframes together:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [
            1,
            2,
            [{"A": "600", "B": "30", "C": "50"}, {"A": "200", "B": "35", "C": "50"}],
        ],
        [
            2,
            5,
            [{"A": "300", "B": "70", "C": "80"}, {"A": "400", "B": "76", "C": "90"}],
        ],
    ],
    columns='id duration columnA'.split(),
)

print(pd.concat(list(df.columnA.map(json_normalize))))
```

Output:

```
     A   B   C
0  600  30  50
1  200  35  50
0  300  70  80
1  400  76  90
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
df = json_normalize(response, 'columnA', ['A','B','C'])
```

Assuming A, B and C are flat